# Reading images in python using OpenCV and OS libraries

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a folder with numerous images(about 300), I am gonna save the python file which will be splitting the images into red, green and blue channels and saving them as _red, _green, _blue, preceded by the original image name itself in a different folder. For example if the image is named "image 001", then the images obtained after the split are: "image 001_red", "image 001_green", "image 001_blue". Now, is there a way I can obtain the images one after the other using the OS library? (Appreciate any answer what-so-ever, because this is my first question on this site)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking how to read an image list from a directory to python. Here is how.

```
from os import walk

# Get file list
def getImageList(path):
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
        return filenames

# Demo printing file names
filelist = getImageList("path/to/image/dir") 
for fileName in fileList:
    print(fileName)
```

`getImageList(path)` function returns all files (not directories) in a given path. Place all your images inside a directory, and use the function to get the file list.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Actually what I want is to read any and all images available in the folder without knowing the actual names of the files. Is there any ways to do that using the two libraries I mentioned? Btw, your reply was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to know the file names, library does that for you. And also I AM using the `os` library. Glad to help! :)

Comment: You are welcome, consider marking the answer if it helped.